# List of Racket Primitive Functions

Tags: racket, primitive, built-in

Is there a list of Racket built in functions?  Im looking for a list sort of like [this one](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) for python.  I can't seem to find one in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some lists:

The index of all functions in the Racket documentation:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/doc-index.html

A cheat sheet:

https://docs.racket-lang.org/racket-cheat/index.html?q=cheatsheet

Now "primitive function" in the context of Racket means all functions implemented in the virtual machine (i.e. not functions implemented in Racket are excluded), so
a third list might also be relevant.

This small program generates a list of all primitives:

```
#lang racket

(define primitive-table  
  (let ([ns (make-base-empty-namespace)]) ; make namespace with racket/base attached
    (parameterize ([current-namespace ns])
      (namespace-require ''#%kernel)      ; import all primitives
      (namespace-require ''#%unsafe)
      (namespace-require ''#%flfxnum)
      (namespace-require ''#%extfl)
      (namespace-require ''#%futures)
      (namespace-require ''#%foreign)

      (namespace-mapped-symbols))))

primitive-table
```

On my version of Racket there are 1487 primitives.

Comment: Thanks, thats just what I was looking for.  But just out of curiosity, why does racket need so many primitives?  Couldn't some of them be implemented by racket using other primitives?

Comment: The last list will have level procedures and special forms that aren't used by end users since it's lower level than typical scheme primitives. Typically the "primitives" are wrapped procedures and syntax that uses these. You can see this in the IDE by right clicking on symbols and selecting "Open defining file". eg. `map` usually doesn't use the primitive at all in the most common cases. The same can be said for clojure and probably python too.

Comment: @Vityou Racket doesn't *need* that many. That the number is so large is due to multiple reasons. First of all some functions *need* to be primitives (i.e. as C functions). Other functions could be implemented Racket on top of other primitives but aren't. Years ago when Racket didn't have a JIT-compiler a primitive implemented in C would often be faster than a Racket implemtation. Therefore many functions were implemented in C. In later years there has been a movement from C-primitives to Racket implementations. Recent developments such as Typed Racket and a new JIT-compiler implemented in

Comment: Racket will without doubt speed up the process.